# Meaning of $(VAR): in makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I found in a makefile the following commands:

```
$(var):  
          mkdir -p $(@D)
```

What is the meaning of this command?

Comment: The most important tag (for make) is missing.

Comment: sorry? I don't understand

Comment: You tried to ask about shell variables, but your actual question is clearly actually about a `make` variable.

Comment: Are you sure that "mkdir -p" is really in this line where a colon is in front of it? Is the name of the file really Makefile?

Comment: mkdir -p $(@D)  is not in the same line as $(var)
The command should be : 
$(var):
              mkdir -p $(@D)
The name of the file is really Makefile

Comment: I know that it CAN'T be in the same line - unless it is just some kind of crazy template for a real Makefile. Please edit your question and add the line break because without your question is wrong. See tripleee's answer or my answer. It's a Makefile and not a shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(VAR)` expands to the value of the variable `VAR`. This is a Make variable (not a shell etc variable). For example, if earlier in your `Makefile` you define

```
VAR=ick/poo
```

then `VAR` expands to `ick/poo`, and `@D` in your recipe expands to the directory part, `ick`.

As you seem to be confused about the relationship between shell and `make`, I should perhaps point out that these are two different languages, though in a `Makefile`, you will encounter both; the recipes - the parts which are indented by a tab - will be passed to a shell for evaluation (though normally the shell will be `/bin/sh`, not Bash, unless you specifically override the Make variable `SHELL` to force it).

In the shell, by the way, the superficially similar construct `$(cmd)` performs a command substitution; that is, the command `cmd` will be evaluated and its output will be inserted as text. So for example,

```
echo Running in $(pwd)
```

will print

```
Running in /home/you
```

if executed in the directory `/home/you` (the command `pwd` prints out your current working directory). ... Though in a `Makefile`, the dollar sign will normally be evaluated and consumed by `make` itself; so to pass a literal dollar sign to the shell, you have to double it.

```
test:
    echo Running in $$(pwd)
```

Comment: ... Though in GNU Make, you can use the built-in variable `$(CURDIR)` instead of running a separate subshell just to obtain the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

As already explained by @tripleee `$(var)` expands to the variable. Because it is here listed before a colon it means that it is a target in a Makefile.

For `$(@D)` see [10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) in the make manual:

> The directory part of the file name of the target, with the trailing slash removed. If the value of ‘$@’ is dir/foo.o then ‘$(@D)’ is dir. This value is . if ‘$@’ does not contain a slash.

NOTE: This is NOT a shell script. This is a makefile. Please use "man make" for a description about what "make" does.

Comment: @jww: Big thanks for proper formatting. Will remember this!